# Rails activerecord - weird sql queries after upgrading ruby and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, passenger

We have a Rails 3.2.19 application. After upgrading Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.5 and Phusion Passenger 3.0.19 to 4.0.57, activerecord generated some incomplete SQL queries and tried to execute against MYSQL server. It was weird.

1. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: [34816] syntax error: improper query string termination: SELECT
2. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: [8192] Relation not found: no such relation ": SELECT `
3. Mysql2::Error: [32768] Translate error: SQL-ERROR: unable to resolve relation "": SELECT  `agents`.* FROM `agents`  WHERE ``.`id` = 22241082 LIMIT 1
4. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: [32769] Unknown column: SQL-ERROR: unable to resolve column "agents.: SELECT  `agents`.* FROM `agents`  WHERE `agents`.`

All the above sql statements are invalid. We didn't do any application code change. Can anybody let me know, where things might have gone wrong? I couldn't find any information on internet like this.

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: Are you sure the gem versions are up to date in production?

Comment: @engineersmnky We bundle all the gems with rails app itself. So there is no place for gem version mismatch. even if that is the case, will it behave like this?